# What's the purpose of Button stretching option in xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode

I don't understand what stretching option(from Attributes Inspector of `UIButton`) is. Could someone explain about the purpose of **stretching option** of UIButton?

I fully understand `UIImage` stretching principle and I usually use the stretching option for PNG images. But, UIButton stretching does not work for any image, especially for the **Background Image** of UIButton.

Please do not comment about *Image Slicing*. My topic is not asking about slicing.

Here is my case:

[image]

Above is my original image and of size 74x74. If I use UIImage stretching option like this: `"X: 0.5, Y: 0.5, Width: 0, Height: 0"` in **Attributes Inspector** in Xcode 8, I can get pure stretched image like below:

[image]

However, once I apply this Image to UIButton Background Image, it has no stretching effect.

Can anybody explain about UIImage stretching option or why is this needed for UIButton? Please give me comments about it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are modifying `contentStretch` property.Defines the stretchable and nonstretchable regions of a view.Using x,y,width and height properties you can define the region to stretch.

For example x = 0 , y = 0 , width = 1 and height = 0 means , view's entire area is stretchable.

Content stretching is often used to animate the resizing of a view. For example, buttons and other controls use stretching to maintain crisp borders while allowing the middle portions of the control to stretch and fill the available space.

You can find more details here - [contentStretch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622511-contentstretch)